# In this simple Bayesian logistic-regression model, why isn't uncertainty about the mean increasing uncertainty about predictions?

Tags: bayesian, binomial-distribution, prediction

Either my intuition is misleading me or my code is wrong. In a nutshell, I have a simple logistic-regression model, and when I look at the posterior distribution of μ, a given unit's probability of succeeding on each trial, I see substantial uncertainty (i.e., variability in the posterior distribution), but when I look at the posterior predictive distribution for a sum of these trials, it looks the same as the binomial distribution implied by a point estimate of μ. Where did the variability go?

Here are the details, in R. I generate the data:

```
ilogit = function(x) 1 / (1 + exp(-x))

set.seed(10)
N = 20
n = 5
dat =
    transform(f = n - y,
    transform(y = rbinom(N, n, mu),
    transform(mu = ilogit(1 + x1 + x2),
    data.frame(x1 = rnorm(N), x2 = rnorm(N)))))
```

and fit the model:

```
fit = glm(data = dat, family = binomial(link = "logit"),
    cbind(y, f) ~ x1 + x2)
```

We'll look at inferences for the first subject (the first row of `dat`). To get a predictive distribution for `y` using only a point estimate of `mu` (namely, `fitted(fit)[1]`), we can do this:

```
plot(table(rbinom(5000, n, fitted(fit)[1])))
```

[image: Figure 1]

This procedure doesn't account for uncertainty about `mu`. To do that in a Bayesian fashion, we can use `sim` from the `arm` package.

```
library(arm)
sims = sim(fit, 5000)@coef
mu.post = ilogit(
    sims[,"(Intercept)"] +
    sims[,"x1"] * dat$x1[1] +
    sims[,"x2"] * dat$x2[1])
```

Here's a 95% credible interval for this subject's `mu`, showing substantial uncertainty.

```
> quantile(mu.post, c(.025, .975))
     2.5%     97.5% 
0.5528186 0.7749029
```

We can now plot the real posterior predictive distribution by drawing one point from a binomial distribution per sample of the posterior of `mu`.

```
plot(table(rbinom(5000, n, mu.post)))
```

[image: Figure 2]

Which looks the same as the first plot! What's going on?

Now, if you set `N` to something small, like 5, these figures will no longer match. It makes sense to me that they should indeed match for large `N`, large enough for `mu.post` to be tightly concentrated at a single point. But `N = 20` isn't that large, going by `quantile(mu.post, c(.025, .975))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly, the variability in your `mu.post` is indeed small enough to cause this effect.  To see this, observe that `mu.post` has a mean of roughly 0.66 and, if we assume it's close to normally distributed, a standard deviation of only about 0.055 (based on the 2.5th and 97.5th percentiles).  That actually is not very big. Now, simulate 5000 binomials with n=5 and p=0.66 and compare with 5000 binomials with n=5 and p~N(0.66,0.055):

```
x <- rbinom(5000,5,0.66)
x2 <- rbinom(5000,5,rnorm(5000,0.66,0.055))
sd(x)
[1] 1.053512
sd(x2)
[1] 1.081202

table(x)/5000
x
     0      1      2      3      4      5 
0.0032 0.0450 0.1732 0.3328 0.3226 0.1232 
table(x2)/5000
x2
     0      1      2      3      4      5 
0.0050 0.0494 0.1760 0.3180 0.3242 0.1274
```

The two tables differ by only 0.0148 at 3 and much less at the other possible values.